# Powershell to split a string into an array by start and end characters

Tags: arrays, powershell, split

Given values to extract from a string, where each value is surrounded by a starting character and ending character, what would be the most effective way to achieve this?

eg, to get an array containing values: a b c

```
$mystring = "=a; =b; =c;"
$CharArray = $mystring.Split("=").Split(";")
```

Comment: `($mystring -replace '=|;').Split(' ')` works for this case. `$mystring.Split("=").Split(";").Trim() -ne ''` also works. `($mystring -replace ' ?=|;').ToCharArray()` also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are numerous combinations of `-replace`, `-split`, `.Split()`, and `.Replace()` that could be used for this task. Here are some examples:

```
# Since each element is separated by a space, you can replace extraneous characters first
# -split operator alone splits by a space character
# This can have issues if your values contain spaces too
($mystring -replace '=|;').Split(' ')
-split ($mystring -replace '=|;')

# Since splitting creates white space at times, `Trim()` handles that.
# Because you expect an array after splitting, -ne '' will only return non-empty elements
$mystring.Split("=").Split(";").Trim() -ne ''

# Creates a array of of System.Char elements. Take note of the type here as it may not be what you want.
($mystring -replace ' ?=|;').ToCharArray()

# Uses Split(String[], StringSplitOptions) method
($myString -replace ' ?=').Split(';',[StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Answer (score 0):

David, what you have looks good yet here is another way to do it.  The -replace method handles the space (" ") and equal sign (=).

```
$mystring = "=a; =b; =c;"
$CharArray = $mystring -split ";" -replace " |=",""
```